# como mantener mi conexión a mi base de datos con java?

Tags: java, mysql

tengo una aplicacion de escritorio donde me conecto a un base de datos MySQL,el programa funciona bien y la conexión también, el problema es que hay una parte del programa donde el usuario llena varios datos y se demora maso menos de 10 minutos y después de eso recién le da al botón guardar y ahí se vuelve a usar la conexión de la base de datos, pero en este instante me sale un error que por lo que he averiguado sucede por que dejo de usar la conexión con la base de datos por mucho tiempo,espero su ayuda gracias,

**Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms**

Comment: teoricamente debes tener una cadena de conexión, y debes abrir y cerrar las conexiones cada que interactuas con tu base de datos, así que, en teoría, abre una conexión antes de realizar una operación con tu base de datos. PD: adjunta código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: sin el código es dificil ayudarte, pero deberías de hacer las operaciones antes de cerrar la conexión de base de datos

Comment: gracias por responder,claro cada vez que utilizo la conexion abro y luego se cierra, la conexion funciona correctamente siempre en cuando sea seguido, el problema es cuando la dejo de usar por un tiempo ahi me sale el error, por eso pregunto como podria mantener mi conexion abierta por mas tiempo

Comment: Creo que estás cargando el objeto pesado (EntityManagerFactory) constantemente... es lo primero que se me viene a la cabeza... pero si pones código, te ayudaremos mejor.